# Always include children even if condition is false

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular templates, is there a way to conditionally include an element, but always include its children?

`*ngIf` will always remove the children as well, so that doesn't work here.

A *simplified* example:

```
<mySpecialElement>
   <span>Hello World!</span>
</mySpecialElement>
```

Basically, I want the existence of `mySpecialElement` to be gated behind a condition. But if the condition is false, I still want the inner `<span>` to show.

Is this possible?

Comment: i think the best is to show always your child component, pass your condition to it (the child), and he adapt its view through the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If `mySpecialElement` is not rendered, neither will its child elements. But you might try to always render your element, but conditionally render other DOM elements inside it.

For example, `MySpecialElement`'s template might look like this:

```
<div *ngIf="someCondition()">...</div>
<span>Hello World!</span>
```